# Ajax can't find my function in Controller url/path is wrong(orchard)mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, orchardcms

Hello i have build  ajax that call my function in Control.
this project in Orchard(new in that) it is like mvc  as i know.

I have problem with url/path to the function.

if i use  `url: '@Url.Action("GetFilesList", "FileUpload")'` NOT working

I know that in '@Url.Action first value is my function name , and secont is my controller name(without controller it self)

but like that  with direct  url to function  it is working

```
'http://localhost:30321/OrchardLocal/VnModule.Module/FileUpload/GetFilesList'
```

This my code:
Work:

```
  $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:30321/OrchardLocal/VnModule.Module/FileUpload/GetFilesList',
        type: 'POST',

        data: {
            sNum: "123",
            __RequestVerificationToken: token
        },

        success: function () {
        },
        error: function () {

        }
    });
```

And this is not working:

```
 $.ajax({
        url:'@Url.Action("GetFilesList", "FileUpload")',
        type: 'POST',

        data: {
            sNum: "123",
            __RequestVerificationToken: token
        },

        success: function () {
        },
        error: function (xhr) {

        }
    });
```

My controller:

```
namespace VnModule.Module.Controllers
{
    public class FileUploadController : Controller
    {
    [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [ActionName("GetFilesList")]
        public void GetFilesList(string sNum)
        {
            int myNumber = Int32.Parse(sNum);
        }

   }

}
```

Sow i sure that problem is in  `url: '@Url.Action("GetFilesList", "FileUpload")'`  but i cant understand what i am doing wrong.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Does it an external js file ?

Comment: This is js file is in Script folder,and comtroller in folder Controllres

Comment: Url.Action is razor html helper and it won't work in external js files. `url:'/FileUpload/GetFilesList'` is ok to use.

Comment: if i put my js file to Controllers folder Url.Action is gona work?

Comment: Not file, js code should be on the view to use Razor html helpers.

Comment: Like others have said you will need to move your script to a Razor (.cshtml) file if you want to use the Url.Action method. If you don't want to move the entire script to a razor view then just make a global js variable like `var getFileListUrl = '@Url.Action("GetFilesList", "FileUpload")'` and then reference that variable in the js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution how to see the url ( Url.Action razor) , in external js file;

i have  added data-id with this path to my button like this:

```
   <input type="submit" value="Savee" id="btn_UploadImg" onclick="btn_Upload_Click(this)" data-urlaction="@Url.Action("GetFilesList", "FileUpload", new { area = "VnModule.Module" })" />
```

And to get this Url Action path in external js file you can like this:

```
 var funcUrl = $("#btn_UploadImg").data("urlaction");



 $.ajax({
        url: funcUrl,

        type: 'POST',

        data: {
            sNum: "123",
            __RequestVerificationToken: token
        },

        success: function () {
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert("Error:"+xhr.responseText);
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
            console.info(xhr);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

[Orchard Documentation link about module](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Building-a-hello-world-module/)

Every module in Orchard CMS is an area of ASP.NET MVC project. So You need to add area attribute in your code like as:

```
url: '@Url.Action("GetFilesList", "FileUpload", new{area = "module name here"})'
```

This way your problem should be solved.

Comment: No sorry..it is still not working..i tried VnModule.Module and VnModule and Vn

Comment: This code should work for you, but to debug your problem can you paste the output html here (You can get it from browser page source)

Answer (score 0):

Check your URL in network panel and identified which URL is called in ajax request It's help you a lot to find a solution and as per orchard if it is required to pass area then change `@Url.Action` accordingly.